# java validate String containing numbers and search to make sure there are no characters

Tags: java, string, validation, input

I want to validate a user input phone number, the first thing I need to do is check to make sure that the length of the input string is 10 which isn't an issue as you'll see in my code.

Now is where the problem comes in, I also need to check to make sure no characters have been entered in as well, any ideas on how to do this with out the use of Arrays. I'd like to use Character.isLetter(); but no matter how I implement it it's not coming out right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      boolean isNumber = false; 
      String phoneNum = "";
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(!isNumber)
        {
           System.out.print("\nEnter your 10 digit phone number (ex: 2123345657): ");         
           phoneNum = input.nextLine(); 

             /* Yes I could use nextInt(); etc.. but that would defeat the 
              purpose of this exercise */

              if(phoneNum.length() != 10)
              {
                System.out.println("\n\nBad input");
              }
              else 
                  isNumber = true;
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nPhone number is: " + phoneNum);


   }

}
```

I was looking for some thing like this.

```
while(!isRight)
    {
            System.out.print("\n input number: "); 
            phoneNum = input.nextLine();  

            while(i < phoneNum.length())
            {   
                if(phoneNum.length() != 10)
                {
                    System.out.println("not enough numbers");
                } 


                else if (Character.isLetter(phoneNum.charAt(i)) == true)
                {   

                    System.out.println("Sorry you can't use any thing but numbers");
                }

                else 
                    isRight = true;
                i++;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post the solution I came up with, for a few reasons but mainly so that if so some one is having issues and they're intentionally avoiding Arrays, regex etc.. they can have a good example!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       boolean isNumber = false; 
       String phoneNum = "";
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

       while(!isNumber)
       {
            isNumber = true;
            System.out.print("\nEnter your 10 digit phone number (ex: 4142317534): ");
            phoneNum = input.nextLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < phoneNum.length(); i++)
            {
               if(!Character.isDigit(phoneNum.charAt(i)))
               {
                  isNumber = false;
               }
            }


            if(phoneNum.length() != 10)
            {
              isNumber = false;
            }


            if(isNumber == false)
            {
               System.out.println("\n\nInvalid format - please reenter");
            }
       }

       System.out.println("\n\nPhone Number: " + phoneNum);

    }


}
```

Yes it's a lot of code yes it can be condensed, but it's more important to learn and understand how things work and why they work they way they do before you attempt to be efficient, efficiency comes with learning and working the more you do the better you get and the more waste you cut out!

Answer (score 1):

use a regex of

```
"^[0-9]{10}"
```

or if it has to start with non-zero

```
"^[1-9][0-9]{9}"  

if(!phoneNum.matches("^[0-9]{10}")) {
   // ok
}
```

If you want to use `isLetter`

then try

```
boolean allNum = true;
for (char ch : phoneNum.toCharArray ()) {
   if (Character.isLetter (ch)) {
       allNum = false;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not `^[0-9]{10}`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Because my coffee machine was broken this morning

Comment: Yes I could do it that way how ever I was hoping for some thing that used the Character.isLetter() method. I just can't seem to implement correctly.

Comment: Why `Character.isLetter` rather than `Character.isDigit`?

Comment: Yes but what I was trying to do was when the condition is checked if a character is found, isLetter(); would return true and and the statement would execute producing the output that tells the user characters are not allowed. The result from isLetter(); or isDigit(); would be the same if done slightly differently.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your comment

Comment: Which one lol, the one directly above yours was directed at Andy Turner, I should have been more specific about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a regex:

```
boolean validate(String str) {
  if (str.length() != 10) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String regex matching to check whether string is a numeric or not:

```
boolean numeric = phoneNum.matches("\\d+");
```

As an alternative solution, if you have apache commons library imported in the project, you can use `isNumeric` method of `StringUtils` class, e.g.:

`StringUtils.isNumeric(phoneNum);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
/* Check is numeric */

```
StringUtils.isNumeric(yourNumber);
```

or REGEX to avoid all characters diferente of numbers.

```
 `{\\d+}`
```